# TextBox - TextChanged event Windows C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am stuck into a problem and need inputs. Here is the description -

I have a `txtPenaltyDays` in windows form C#

```
private void txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Convert.ToInt16(txtPenaltyDays.Text) > 5)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("The maximum amount in text box cant be more than 5"); 
    txtPenaltyDays.Text = 0;// Re- triggers the TextChanged 
  }
}
```

But I am running into problem because this fires 2 times. Because of setting the text value to 0.
My requirement is that it should fire only one time and set the value to 0.

Any suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Comment: a more serious problem. What happen if your user types a letter ?

Comment: if(txtPenaltyDays.Text=="0") return;

Comment: Yes steve its true . this is just a part of code i tried to put . But in actual code i have key-press event handling all the special characters

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just disable the event handler when you discover the invalid value, inform the user and then reenable the event handler

```
 private void txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   short num;
   if(Int16.TryParse(txtPenaltyDays.Text, out num))
   {
       if(num > 5)
       {
           txtPenaltyDays.TextChanged -= txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged;
           MessageBox.Show("The maximum amount in text box cant be more than 5"); 
           txtPenaltyDays.Text = "0";//
           txtPenaltyDays.TextChanged += txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged;
       }
   }
   else
   {
      txtPenaltyDays.TextChanged -= txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged;
      MessageBox.Show("Typed an invalid character- Only numbers allowed"); 
      txtPenaltyDays.Text = "0";
      txtPenaltyDays.TextChanged += txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged;
   }
 }
```

Notice also that I have removed the Convert.ToInt16 because it fails if your user types a letter instead of a number and used Int16.TryParse

Comment: Thanks Steve...that works! Thanks guys for your inputs however i understand that private variable option was not a good one because this will prevent re-trigger on application level.

Comment: Did you consider to use the NumericUpDown control? It has Minimum and Maximum properties that control the allowable values. And it removes the key press handling code. For simple scenarios it is a valuable option

Answer (score 4):

You can use a private form field to keep the event from firing the 2nd time:

```
private bool _IgnoreEvent = false;

private void txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
   if (_IgnoreEvent) { return;}
   if(Convert.ToInt16(txtPenaltyDays.Text)>5)
    MessageBox.Show("The maximum amount in text box cant be more than 5"); 
    _IgnoreEvent = true;
    txtPenaltyDays.Text = 0;// Re- triggers the TextChanged, but will be ignored 
    _IgnoreEvent = false;
 }
```

A better question would be, "should I do this in `TextChanged`, or would it be better to do it in `Validating`?"

Comment: This is the best method. Adding and removing events for something so small is not a good pattern

Answer (score 3):

Try following code

```
private void txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(Convert.ToInt16(txtPenaltyDays.Text)>5)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("The maximum amount in text box cant be more than 5"); 
      txtPenaltyDays.TextChanged -= txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged; 
      txtPenaltyDays.Text = 0;// Re- triggers the TextChanged 
      txtPenaltyDays.TextChanged += txtPenaltyDays_TextChanged;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the event Leave or LostFocus instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if textbox is not focused then fire the event:

`if (!textbox1.Focused) return;`

or bind and unbind the event:

`textbox1.TextChanged -= textbox1_TextChanged;
 textbox.Text = "some text";
 textbox1.TextChanged += textbox1_TextChanged;`