# Winform textbox and how to check when changing the contents

Tags: c#, winforms

If I close the screen when I  work on the not save document,
Do you want to save changes to Untitled? pop-up.

I want to use a similar method in C# winForm. I want to know how to detect when it changes, such as modifying textBox, modifying comboBox, or modifying RadioButton.

Thank you

Comment: To abstract so an abstract answer. In a somewhat decent architecture here a dialog is designed to show data from a model(class). So input to the form is a model and output after doing something is also a model(class). And there you can check if the input model equals the output model. If they are not equal then ask to save.

Answer (score 1):

For TextBox, use the TextChanged event see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) on MSDN and [this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284487/textbox-textchanged-event-windows-c-sharp).

Similarly, for ComboBox, use [SelectedIndexChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged?view=windowsdesktop-6.0).

For radio button, [OnCheckedChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.oncheckedchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0).

Keep a boolean variable flag (some people like to call it "isDirty") which you set to false right after saving, and set it to true when something changes, in the event handlers mentioned above.

On [FormClosing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.oncheckedchanged?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), check the flag, and ask the user. You can cancel closing the form by setting the `Cancel` property on the `FormClosingEventArgs`.